# passing parameters between pages with jqm.page.params.js in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

i have thise code to display a listview in jquery mobile :

`$('#actualites').append('<li><a data-transition="slide" href="actualite.htm?id=' + id +    '&titre=' + titre + '&contenu=' + contenu + '&date=' + date + '&type=' + type + '&image=' + image + '"><img src="' + image + '" height="100%" width="100%"/><h3>' + titre + '</h3><p>' + contenu + '</p></a></li>');
$('#actualites').listview('refresh');`

i added this file : 
`<script src="js/jqm.page.params.js"></script>`

and on index, i added this to get params :

```
$("#actualite").live("pagebeforeshow", function(e, data){
            if ($.mobile.pageData && $.mobile.pageData.titre){
                console.log("Parameter titre=" + $.mobile.pageData.titre);
            }
        });
```

to get titre but it is undefined...so do i forget anything ?

thanks

Comment: i did that without and it doesn't work too :
    `$("#actualite").live("pagebeforeshow", function(e, data){
          console.log("Parameter titre = " + data.options.pageData.titre);
   });`

Comment: i have this error :

Cannot read property 'pageData' of undefined

Comment: when i debug and see attributes of data, i have only : prevPage